# Let's encrypt csr with ECC (P-521)

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to generate a certificate for my web server with Let's Encrypt. I want to manually generate key and csr with openssl, and then use letsencrypt / certbot to get the certificate. I specifically want the certificate to use `sha256withecdsa`. In particular I would like to use the curve `secp521r1` (a.k.a. `P-521`).

The key generation and csr generation work fine, however, when I input the command

```
certbot certonly --apache -d [censored] --csr mycsr.csr --agree-tos
```

I get the following error:

> The request message was malformed :: Invalid key in certificate request :: ECDSA curve P-521 not allowed

Is `ECDSA` still unsupported, or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

While P-521 is [valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480) for use in X.509 certificates, most browsers dropped support for it as it is not a part of [Suite B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_Suite_B_Cryptography) and isn't very popular. As a result, Certbot [doesn't allow](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2163) certificates to be generated using P-521 since the browsers would reject it anyway. You can still generate certificates using the P-256 and P-384 curves. See the [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1128792) and [Google](https://boringssl-review.googlesource.com/c/2843/) bugreports for details.

Comment: Also per https://letsencrypt.org/upcoming-features/, Let's Encrypt signs ECDSA based certificates since February 2016 albeit with  RSA based root and intermediate certificates, and is planned in Q3 2018 to have an ECDSA based root and intermediates certificates.

Comment: The 2 bugreports you quote do not really show removal of P-521 from browsers, quite the contrary in fact. P-521 has been removed from BoringSSL based on https://boringssl-review.googlesource.com/c/boringssl/+/2860 but this seems kind of reversed in https://boringssl-review.googlesource.com/c/boringssl/+/10923 "This intentionally leaves the P-521 hooked up for now. Detaching it
completely is a more aggressive change (since it's slightly tied up with
SHA-512) that should wait until removing ECDSA+SHA512 has stuck in Chrome."So it may be removed from the "default" list but still be implemented.

Comment: The main point was that P521 in particular was unsupported by the certbot tool for the reasons I mentioned above. General ECDSA support in Letsencrypt has been around for a while, and those ECDSA roots can't come soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Besides my comments on @AfroThundr reply, in fact the definitive source of information on this is https://letsencrypt.org/docs/integration-guide/ and it says:

> Supported Key Algorithms
>
> Let’s Encrypt accepts RSA keys from 2048 to 4096 bits in length, and P-256 and P-384 ECDSA keys. That’s true for both account keys and certificate keys. You can’t reuse an account key as a certificate key.
>
> Our recommendation is to serve a dual-cert config, offering an RSA certificate by default, and a (much smaller) ECDSA certificate to those clients that indicate support.